# How do I keep all elements inside a box in the middle of the box?

Tags: html, css

How do I keep the input box in the middle of the green box? [image: the page]

Github-Link for the page: https://tahsinttalha.github.io/fcc-survey-form/

I have tried magin property to center the inout boxes. But in small screen, It's not working properly. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use padding inside the main container, so all the div and block elements will take 100% of the width.

Just need to put width: 100% to all inputs.

I made a basic example :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: lime;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.description {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.form-input, select-input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 1rem 0 ;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.select-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">
      Personal Survey
    </h1>
    <p class="description">
      This survey is being conducted solely for the purpose of the developement of the website. Your data is safe and secured and we will be disposed of the data after our   analysis is completed. Thank your very much for your time and effort.
    </p>
  <form action="#">
    <label for="" class="form-label">
      Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Type your name">
        <label for="" class="form-label">
      Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Type your email">
        <label for="" class="form-label">
      Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Type your age">
    <div class="select-container">
      <select class="select-input" name="" id="dropdown">        
        <option value="Select">Select your profession type</option>
        <option value="">option 1</option>
        <option value="">option 2</option>
        <option value="">option 3</option>
        <option value="">option 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried box sizing and it worked. But thanks anyway ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the CSS-definition of your input:

```
#input-info-section > input,
#dropdown,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 2px solid #333333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    /* add the following line: */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This way, the paddings and borders are calculated with all other measurements and not added after centering the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Iam trying this 

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flex` to keep elements in the middle of box.like:

```js
<div class="box">
  <input />
</div>
```

add CSS to the `div`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Wait, I used flex and justify-content but nothing happened? Is flex-direction must?

Comment: flex-direction is not must! You can refer to this article [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to check whether your code is correct, or you can post the code and I will help you solve it